# Order product list by creation date

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was adding date to sorting methods in catalog list. If I chose sort by date, list is sorting by date - this is working good. 
But, what should i do for set default sort by date (DESC) in catalog list? 
In my case, not working these solutions: 
catalog.xml

```
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
<action method="setDefaultOrder"><field>created_at</field></action>
```

and:
 
Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
protected $_direction = 'desc';
```

Magento Version: 1.7.0.2.

**Edit: 1**

I made a new module in local folder /app/code/local/SortByDate/. I added two files. First /catalog/model/Config.php:

```
class SortByDate_Catalog_Model_Config extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Config {

    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = parent::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
        if (!isset($options['created_at'])) {
            $options['created_at'] = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Date');
        }
        return $options;
    }

}
```

and second /etc/config.xml :

```
 <config><global><models><catalog><rewrite><config>SortByDate_Catalog_Model_Config</config></rewrite></catalog></models></global></config>
```

**Edit 2 - Solved**
I modify this function, problem was gone :)

```
        public function setDefaultOrder($field)
    {
//set default order by date
        if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
                         $this->_availableOrder = array(
                                'created_at' => $this->__('Date'),
                'name'        => $this->__('Name'),
                'price'       => $this->__('Price'),
            );
            $this->_orderField = $field;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly did you add the date to the sorting methods in the catalog list? `created_at` is not an EAV attribute, so you did not do this via the backend I guess. Please give more details in your question.

Comment: I added "Edit: 1" paragraf for you. Could you check this?

Comment: Btw, on StackOverflow (S.O.) an encouraged workflow when you discover the answer to your own question independent of S.O. is to answer it and accept your own answer. Not only does it give people the opportunity to reward you for your good question and answer, it also makes the question more visible for future people, and encourages other people to post solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I modify this function, problem was gone :)

```
    public function setDefaultOrder($field)
    {
    //set default order by date
        if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
                         $this->_availableOrder = array(
                                'created_at' => $this->__('Date'),
                'name'        => $this->__('Name'),
                'price'       => $this->__('Price'),
            );
            $this->_orderField = $field;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and in order to fix it for all my websites in a clean way I've developed an extension that does the trick.

It's free and pretty easy to install and use. Fell free to download it.

https://magento.mdnsolutions.com/extensions/mdn-sort-by-date.html

Cheers,

Renato